# Intel oneAPI MKL (Fourier Transform Functions)

Tags: fourier-transform

I am learning the Fourier transform from examples and one particular statement in the comment,

> According to the Fourier Transform theory, FFT result is sized N/2+1 for 1D FFT...

in the below link to the example

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/use-onemkl-with-opencv-for-fft-calculation.html?wapkw=mkl_malloc%20MKL_complex16

is not clear at all. Why the resulting FFT size is `N/2+1` and what theory do they refer?

This complete comment is for the quick reference

> /* Storage for raw FFT result
> Result of FFT will be saved as an array of complex numbers.
> MKL provides a data type called MKL_Complex16. According to the Fourier Transform theory,
> FFT result is sized N/2+1 for 1D FFT, and (W/2+1)*H for 2D FFT.
> MKL also provides malloc function called mkl_malloc to make sure memory size of the vari-
> able is 4K (default memory page size) aligned. This ensures a high-speed calculation.
> */

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FFT is a an implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) which is defined as

$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j2pi\frac{kn}{N}}$$

The input is a complex array of length $N$ and so is the output. If the input is real, i.e. $x[n] \in \mathbb{R}$, then the output has Hermitian symmetry:

$$X[-k] = X^*[k]$$

The values at negative frequency are the conjugate complex of the positive ones. That means the output has only $N/2+1$ independent values.

A direct consequence of the definition is also that both $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ are periodic with, i.e. $X[k+N]$ = $X[k]$. From that it follows that for a real input the values at $k=0$ and $k=N/2$ must be real as well. The independent output of a real valued FFT has (strictly speaking) 2 real numbers and $N/2-1$ complex numbers which makes for a total of $N$ real numbers.

Most FFT implementations for real input take advantage of the redundancy and do not calculate or return the values at negative frequencies. The exact data format varies from one implementation to the next so you need to read the documentation.

Comment: The exponent should be $e^{-2\pi i \frac{kn}{N}}$ i.e., with $-$ sign?

Comment: yes. fixed. thanks